# Find variable in files using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I want read out variable which is mentioned below in file.

```
#define xyz_u8 abc_0x0_u8 = 0x0 (for hex)
#define xyz_f16 abc_MOD1_f32 = -0.1f (for int and float)
#define xyz abc_YY = YY_ZZ (for others)
```

I am using

```
re.compile(r"^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)")
```

for reading hex, but i am not able to get value from '='. Can anyone correct the regular expression.

Comment: What about a mere `.*` or `.+` at the end? Try [`(?i)^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+) = (.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/jF2zI3/1)

Comment: Thanks wiktor .it worked.

Comment: Great, I added an answer with explanation.

Comment: Wiktor, How can i find regex for 'SET_abc_1(GET_xyz_2())' i am trying as re.compile(r"^(SET\w+)(GET\w+)") but it is not searching. Also i want to find variable like this "SET_abc(GET_xyz()/2 + GEt_qwe_3()/2)"

Comment: Isn't it a new question already? No idea what you need, really. Try [`(SET\w+)\((GET\w+)(?:(?:\([^()]*\)/\d+)?\W+(GET\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/aJ9hC6/1).

Comment: Yes it could have been a different question but it was a part of reg expression so i asked here itself. Thanks for you support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+) = (.+)
```

Use it with the `re.I` and `re.M` (if you have multiline input).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF2zI3/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string (or line if `re.M` is used)
- `#define` - a sequence of literal characters
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) chars
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 capturing one or more word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) chars
- `=`  - space, `=`, space (you may add `+` after each space to allow 1 or more spaces, or `*` to allow 0 or more spaces)
- `(.+)` - Group 3 that will capture the rest of the line.

Comment: If the answer worked for you please consider accepting it. If you have a new question, please ask.